# Got a new job but currently on vacation

Tags: new-job

As the title says I was called for a new job, while I am on vacation at the current job.

I signed my contract yesterday and they expect me to be on site on October 14, but I don’t come back from my vacation till October 3rd.

Been thinking to go into my (current) place of employment this Friday, September 27th, to inform them and resign give my two weeks.

However, I don’t come back till Wednesday, October 3rd. Should I wait till at least Monday?

Either way I want it to be known I will not be here after October 13.

Comment: Did you know about your vacation dates when you negotiated starting dates?

Comment: Either I'm missing something or there was a typo. You come back from holiday on Oct 3rd and have to be on site Oct 14th, I don't see any issue?  

Either way, when discussing employment or a contract, you should always mention existing holiday plans.

Comment: I *think* op is saying he has vacation at his current job and doesn't know if he should resign before or after it @blub

Comment: @Blub There's a two week notice period, so needs to be time for that notice period to be submitted and served.

Comment: @Snow: we cannot be sure about the notice period, since we do not know the country. At the previous job I had a notice period of about (over?) 20 working days - and I was not a manager.

Comment: The question states "give my two weeks", if that doesn't refer to a notice period, then I have no idea what that refers to.

Comment: @Snow: Your point is good. However, the text is quite badly written, it's possible that OP uses the "two weeks" as a synonym for notice period, instead of literally two weeks.

Comment: Yes my original post is poorly written sorry guys it’s early. But my main point in the question is I got a new job while I’m on vacation from another job do I go in early and inform them that I will be leaving the company my start date has to be before October 14. Or do I go in on 3 October and say hey I got a new job I have to leave before the 14th. I’ve never quit while on vacation not sure if that is respectful and courteous to my employer but I’d rather tell them now then later when I come back because either way I’m leaving my contract is signed

Comment: Is "two weeks" notice required by contract, required by local law, or not actually required at all but an "unwritten custom." I believe that in most of the USA it is the last one or nothing at all.

Comment: My employment is at will I can leave whenever I just don’t want to burn any bridges between me and this employer

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely announce your resignation early enough.

Also, be careful about the company's policies, about mixing resignations and vacations. Some companies do not allow using the notice period for vacations.

Comment: Yea I was thinking of going in Friday and just explaining I got this offer while on vacation now my new employer doesn’t know I’m on vacation it’s terrible for me to say but I wanted to relax I don’t really get time off from my current job and it’s already stressful so I proposed that I tell my current employer Monday I will be leaving immediately my last day being October 13th

Comment: Depends on the location, @virolino. Here in the UK the _employee_ gets to decide whether they take the unused vacation days, or take cash in lieu. There are situations where the employer has a policy of immediate termination, in which case its either pay-in-lieu of notice or paid time off ("garden leave")...I'm not really sure what happens in these cases with the unused vacation; just extra pay/days off, I suppose.

Comment: @Justin: that is exactly the point - it depends on the country and it depends on the company. Even if we know the country, the company policies can bring their own surprises.

Answer (score 1):

I was nearly in this position in 2011 (IIRC). I *dreaded* the idea of calling my boss while on vacation and giving her that news.  I ultimately decided *not* to take the new job (due to other considerations, not due to the potential awkwardness of the phone call I was going to have to make). But that's what I would suggest: Call your manager, today, and give them your notice.

> I wish I could do this in person/I'm sorry this comes on such short notice/I understand the timing here is less than ideal/etc, but I wanted to give you the earliest possible notice that I've decided to pursue another opportunity. Please consider this my notice, and my last day will be October 11.

Depending on your tenure/value to your current employer, they may attempt to counter-offer, so be prepared for that eventuality. What will you do if they offer to match the new salary/benefit/etc.?

My last offer, employer at the time asked if they could counter, and I told them "respectfully, no." Primarily because it was the right time to move and it was a good opportunity, but also because the salary differential was so great that I don't think they could've matched it, and I would not have been comfortable with the arrangement for a few reasons if they had.

> do I go in early and inform them that I will be leaving the company my start date has to be before October 14. Or do I go in on 3 October and say hey I got a new job I have to leave before the 14th. **I’ve never quit while on vacation not sure if that is respectful and courteous to my employer** but I’d rather tell them now then later when I come back because either way I’m leaving

Telling them now maximizes their advance notice. I would consider this *more courteous* than telling them when you return, although a difference of a few days seems pretty negligible. Since you seem to have made up your mind, there's no reason not to tell them *right now*.

It may seem/feel a bit untoward to deliver this news while you're on leave. So what? You have to balance that against the timeliness of the notice. There's no perfect solution. If you were not on leave, would you tell them today? Or would you wait until the 3rd?

I guess I'm having a hard time understanding why (aside from the awkwardness of quitting while on leave) the fact that you're on leave is a serious consideration here. They expect (formally, or probably informally at least here in the US) two weeks advance notice. Give them that.

Comment: This is something that has been on my mind since I signed my contract at my new job, ultimately they can match and counter offer all they want (they won’t this is literally triple my salary) my answer would most likely be no my main concern is that I’m on vacation now I’m not supposed to be in the office till the 3rd of October but out of respect to them I want to tell them sooner rather than the 3rd if I tell them the 27th (tomorrow) they can fix the schedule (since this is a basic retail job) and prepare for my leave

Comment: *I’m not supposed to be in the office till the 3rd of October* or "They don't expect me back until 3rd October"?

Comment: Since it sounds like you're leaving a "basic retail job" for a more professional job that will triple your salary, personally I think you're overthinking it. It's good that you're considering their needs as well, but retail employees are (generally speaking) a dime a dozen. No call/No show is common in that industry, as it is in restaurants and many other "non-professional" occupations. They are likely accustomed to handling short-staff situations, and your departure +/- a few days from official "two weeks" isn't going to bankrupt them.

Comment: Sorry David they don’t expect me back in the office till the 3rd of October. And you are absolutely right in retail especially what I do it’s retail banking I’m a dime a dozen just didn’t know if it was I guess bad to quit while on vacation. It’s an at will employer so I know I can leave whenever I chose but since I’m on vacation I felt like this was tricky

Comment: I personally understand the sentiment that it seems "bad to quit while on vaca", but it's likewise "bad to give < 2 weeks notice", so, pick the lesser of the bads :)  Cheers.